# Is it possible to control the minimum tolerance (allowed space between words)

Tags: tex-core, badness

I have learned to use `\pretolerance` and `\tolerance` but sometimes TeX decides to "compress" the broken line of text within the paragraph by simply using less space between the words on the line, and I don't like it. So, if the commands above specify maximum allowed tolerance for lines, what specifies the **minimum** tolerance - controlling minimum interword spacing across the document?

Comment: tolerance actually is a measure of shrinking as well as stretching, change in either direction contributes to the badness of the paragraph. Unlike stretch though where TeX will over-stretch if it needs to, glue never shrinks more than specified in its shrink component, so that is a hard limit. (set by the font parameters initially as shown in Herbert's answer)

Comment: Are you saying that the shrink factor applied to the glue can only be controlled by the font parameters?

Comment: @amn There are `\spaceskip` and `\xspaceskip` to control the interword spacing.

Comment: @amn no they are set initially by the font parameters but you can change them or set `\spaceskip` mainly I was commenting that tolerance applies to the badness of the paragraph which includes a measure of how tight lines are as well as how loose, and explicit penalties

Answer (score 4):

If you want the interword space never shrinks below the “optimal” interword spacing, then

```
\spaceskip=\fontdimen2\font plus \fontdimen3\font\relax
```

will do. Of course, such a declaration should be integrated in every font changing command, which might be done by adding it to `\selectfont`.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin]{babel} % for hyphenation
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\frenchspacing % you don't really want extra space

\xapptocmd{\selectfont}
  {\spaceskip=\fontdimen2\font plus \fontdimen3\font\relax}
  {}{}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\Large
\lipsum[2]                  

\end{document}
```

[image]

Instead of length based on the font parameters, you might directly use lengths expressed in `em` units, because at the time the setting of `\spaceskip` the font has already been selected.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext

\fontdimen2\font=2\fontdimen2\font  % double interwordspace
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Herbert. It appears that, following your advice with the double interword control command sequence, I can make double space between words. Apart from the fact that I don't really want *double* spacing at all, my goal is really to make sure that the space never shrinks to anything less than that (default space), as I find it pleasing and don't want anything tighter than that. On a related note, if the shrink ratio is constant, perhaps choosing 1.5 space will result in 1.0 being the "tightest"?

Comment: the smallest interword space is 2.5pt by default (`\the\fontdimen2\font`. If you want less or more change that value as I already did.

Comment: I don't want to change the default interword space at all - I want to make sure it does not ever shrink for any line of text, only expand, if necessary.